# redirect con ajax laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy haciendo un formulario dentro de un modal para subir un archivo excel

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="excel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalLabel">Escoja su archivo</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <form id="formImport" action="{{route('user.import')}}" method="POST">
                @csrf
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <i class="fas fa-file-import fa-2x"></i> <input type="file" name="excel" id="excelFile" required>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">volver</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="">Confirmar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

tengo esta función ajax

```js
 $("#formImport").submit(function(e) {
        $('#excel').modal('hide')
        var form = $(this);
        var url = form.attr('action');
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "post",
            data: form,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        })
        .done(function(res){
            console.log(res);
        });
   

});
```

cuando mi controlador procesa los datos me envia un json si el archivo se proceso correctamente o no, pero el res me direcciona a la ruta del controlador y en ella se muestra el json, quiero solamente quedarme en la misma pagina y con ese json mandar un mensaje

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que cambiar tu boton tipo `submit` por un boton normal, tu tienes esto:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="">Confirmar</button>
```

Debes tener:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" id="botonEnviar">Confirmar</button>
```

**Fijate en que se le puso un id al boton.**

Ademas tu evento no debe ser tipo `submit`, si no tipo `click` y **se lo deberas agregar al boton y no a tu formulario**:

```
$("#botonEnviar").click(function(e) {
   ...
   tu codigo
   //Si sigue sin funcionar y te dirige a la pagina
   //Coloca aqui un preventDefault de inicios:
   e.preventDefault();
   ...
}
```

Ademas deberas cambiar una pequeña parte de tu codigo para poder que vaya acorde con lo que tienes en tu ajax, deberas cambiar:

```
var form = $(this);
```

por:

```
var form = $("#formImport");
```

Lo que ocurre con los botones tipo `submit` es que si o si debes usarlos si no estas usando `ajax` porque con estos es que se hace la acción de enviar datos a alguna parte, sin embargo esta acción de **enviar datos** al no hacer uso de `ajax` lo que hace es directamente enviarte a la pagina a la cual te referiste en el action.

Sin embargo como estas usando **ajax**, **no es necesario usar un boton con un atributo type definido como submit**, puesto que al usar **ajax** (que no recarga la pagina), ya no necesitas un boton especial, si no cualquier cosa que desencadene la llamada a tu `ajax`, por ejemplo puedes reemplazar tu boton tipo `submit` con un boton normal y seguira funcionando tu `ajax` sin problemas.

Con la unica diferencia de que ya no se recargara tu pagina ni te enviara al action de tu form (aunque los datos si seran enviados a este).

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, no funciono tampoco. intente colocando el data capturando el excel por el id del input y tampoco, me sigue enviando a la ruta del controlador con el json que retorne

Comment: Acabo de editar la respuesta, porfavor mirala de nuevo tal vez funcione...

Comment: Igual, sigue enviandome a la ruta del action

Comment: Probaste colocando preventDefault dentro del evento click??

Comment: Listo amigo, con el preventDefault  obtiene la respuesta. Muchas gracias